# Burn the [source-code] tag

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request, ambiguous-tags

The [source-code](/questions/tagged/source-code) has been used to ask questions about:

- [The Linux Kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19554753/linux-kernel-memory-management)
- [Scraping HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19563707/how-to-get-the-source-code-from-a-web)
- [Version Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19064696/extract-all-code-committed-by-a-certian-author-in-git)
- [Open Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18582837/open-source-alternative-to-aspose)
- [Code Formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14693339/code-editor-with-arbitrary-text-formatting)
- etc.

Lots of questions use the tag only to indicate "my question is about code" which would apply to 90% of the question on SO.

I suggest we burninate it.